# Using a checkbox to auto-populate a row on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-data-validation

[image]

I  have this spreadsheet which is used for receiving and recording work. SST responses sheet is where people submit requests, Workload is where we record all work.

I'm wanting it so that when someone clicks the checkbox as completed it then populates a line in 'Workload' on the next available blank line with the information.

Answer (score 0):

- use this formula in your Workload sheet:

  ```
  =IFERROR(QUERY({'SST Responses'!A:H}, 
   "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 
    where Col8 = TRUE", 0))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To add a row from one sheet on the next available blank row of another sheet when a checkbox is clicked you should use Google Apps Script or and add-on that does that.

If you go for the Google Apps Script option, then you will require to use on edit or on change triggers to execute the function that will do the row addition. To add this row to the next blank row you you use the appendRow method.